# Jquery Ajax to call mailto

Tags: jquery, mailto

I have a form with multiple checkbox contained email address, user can send message to whatever email address that is ticked/checked with open local email client (eg: outlook express), how can I open local email client (eg: outlook express) from the code below?

```
$("#btn_sendmsg").click(function(){
    var parameters = $('#form1').serialize();
    //alert(parameters);
    $.ajax({
        url: 'ajax_call.php',
        data: parameters,
        type: 'POST',
        success: function(data){
            alert(data);
        }
    });
});
```

ajax_call.php

```
if(!empty($_POST['ids'])){

    foreach($_POST['ids'] as $email){
        if($emails == ""){
            $emails = $email;
        }else{
            $emails .= ";" . $email;
        }
    }

    if(!empty($emails)){
        echo "
        window.location = \"mailto:info@abc.com?cc=boss@abc.com&bcc=".$emails."&subject=Hello\";

    }

}

else if(empty($_POST['ids'])){ 
    echo 'No Recepient Selected';

}
```

Thanks!

Comment: You have missing `$` here `("#btn_sendmsg")`.. -->  `$("#btn_sendmsg")`

Comment: You can try calling the window.location function after the ajax block, not in the ajax_call.php

Comment: @Sudip Pal, thanks for your tips, I moved it to the block.

Answer (score 0):

*change in* PHP :

```
if(!empty($emails)){
        echo "mailto:info@abc.com?cc=boss@abc.com&bcc=".$emails."&subject=Hello";
 }
```

**JS:**

```
$("#btn_sendmsg").click(function(){
    var parameters = $('#form1').serialize();
    //alert(parameters);
    $.ajax({
        url: 'ajax_call.php',
        data: parameters,
        type: 'POST',
        success: function(data){
            if(data.indexOf('mailto') > -1){
             window.location = data;
            }
        }
    });
});
```